# item.url generated at menu issue

Tags: 8, uri

I am working on my client's project and they are using Drupal 8.

I discovered that when one uses http://example.com/index.php to access the webpage, the url generated by the menu items , the index.php part is included, i.e. http://example.com/index.php/aboutus instead of http://example.com/aboutus. And it leads to a wrong page.

And I checked with the template file which generates the menu, the url of the menu is generated by `{{item.url}}`, which item is one single item of items for the available variables in the menu templates.

> Available variables:
>
> -menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
>
> -items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
>
> -attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
>
> -below: The menu item child items.
>
> -title: The menu link title.
>
> -url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
>
> -localized_options: Menu link localized options.

Therefore I am asking if there are ways to get rid of the "index.php" in this case and in order to avoid drupal generating wrong url? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to enable apache `mod_rewrite`. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365161/4988967) as well. To enable `mod_rewrite`, use the following command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then you need to restart apache for the changes to reflect,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Refer [this page](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) for information about clean urls, this might even help.

Answer (score 0):

Render the menu item using link() function in your twig file for example,

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
```

I hope, it would solve your issues